# Update manually my add-on sdk

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there any way to trigger firefox's update check for a specific
extension from the extension's code?

I want to put an update button in my toolbar. When user clicks the
button, the built-in extensions dialog shows and checks for update for
the extension.

Comment: If you upload to addons.mozilla.org it automatically triggers update

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this code out but I believe this should do what you want.  You need to get a reference to the AddonManager so you can lookup your own add-on, from there the `updateListener` will get a notification if an update is available.  When an update is available your add-on may be restarted so I'm not exactly sure what happen there.

```
let self = require('sdk/self');
let { Cu } = require('chrome');
let { AddonManager } = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");
let updateListener = {

  onUpdateAvailable: function onAddonUpdateEnded(aAddon, aInstall) {
    // An update is available
    console.log(aInstall.version);
  },

  onNoUpdateAvailable: function onNoUpdateAvailable(aAddon) {
    // no update available
  },

  onUpdateFinished: function onUpdateFinished() {
    // update of the addon has finished
  }
};

AddonManager.getAddonByID(self.id, function(addon) {
  addon.findUpdates(updateListener, AddonManager.UPDATE_WHEN_USER_REQUESTED);
});
```

Comment: I tried it but without success, Firefox detect when update is available but dont take any action